# add an item to a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in Excel with groups.
But I later realized I wanted to add another item to that group.
How do I add an item without causing another dropdown subgroup?

I am working with about 800 items (job descriptions), but most are designer descriptions (head software engineer, head of software development, etc) so I want to group them all as "Tech," and so on. But with 800 items, I may group catch 50, but them later see 4 more. And don't want layers and layers of nested items.

**As of now, it looks like**

```
Group 1
  item 1
  item 2
  item 3
     added item 4
```

**instead I want**

```
Group 1
  item 1
  item 2
  item 3
  added item 4
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you select fields in the Pivot Table and add them to the `Row Values` section (which I am assuming you're doing), you will get that 'nested' behavior. In your `Group 1` column, do you have any values of `Item 4`? Having a row(s) with a value of `Item 4` for `Group 1` would display as you want.

Comment: @RocketDonkey, they do nest...I did not explain that in the original (I will now)...but I want to avoid 5 lines of nesting.

Comment: Ah, okay your update helps. How much control do you have over your source data? Instead of doing a grouping in the Pivot Table itself, how about adding a `Function` column in your source data and populating it with the corresponding function (Tech, etc.)? That way you could add the `Function` field to your `Row Values` section and it would do the grouping for you. Does that apply to your situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of Excel, Calculated Items might be the way to go to quickly group and ungroup row labels.

Follow the tutorial here to see how these work: [PivotTables: Calculated Items](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2008/05/09/pivottables-calculated-items.aspx)